# I want to click all div boxes on a website using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is it possible to click all div boxes on a website using javascript?

here's the css of the div box:

```
    .bird {
    float: left;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
    top: auto;
    left: auto;
    right: auto;
    bottom: auto;
    z-index: 200;
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
}
```

and this is the javascript i want to use:

```
    var myLinks = document.getElementsByClass("bird");
for (var i = 0; i < myLinks.length; i++) {
  myLinks[i].click();
}
```

Comment: Klick means ? Do you want to remove ?

Comment: i think he means "click"

Comment: i think he means to trigger click on some div's  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no `getElementsByClass`. There's a `getElementsByClassName` but it's not supported in IE8 and earlier.

You can use `document.querySelectorAll(".bird")` (which is [supported](http://caniuse.com/#feat=queryselector) by all modern browsers including IE8 and above) to get your list on IE8 and above and any other modern browser:

```
var myLinks = document.querySelectorAll(".bird");
```

Then your code for looping through the resulting `NodeList` is fine. Note that calling `click` on the element may not completely simulate a click (not least because there's no mouse position information given). To go further in your event simulation, you can use [`createEvent`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/) (for most browsers).

Comment: why to you say that getElementsByClassName has spotty support? according to http://caniuse.com/#search=getElementsByClassName it seems ok

Comment: Can i stop the script and restart it again?

Comment: @schopy: IE8 has more than 20% of the global web browser market. It supports `querySelectorAll` and doesn't support `getElementsByClassName`. "Spotty" might have been a poor word choice, but QSA is definitely better supported than GEBCN -- because of IE8.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try it with jquery? Like this:

```
$('.bird').each(function(){
   $(this).click();
});
```